# Code terminates at if( player == NULL ) in the loadMedia function

Tags: c++, sdl-2

The code terminates once it reaches the if( player == NULL ) statement in the loadMedia function. No errors are given, just ends.

loadMedia function

```
bool loadMedia()
{
  std::cout << "Loading media" << std::endl;

  player = SDL_LoadBMP( "player.bmp" );

  if( player == NULL )
  {
    std::cout << "Media could not be loaded " << static_cast< std::string >( SDL_GetError() );
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Entire code

```
//Johnathan Regha-Dodge: CS_version1

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include "src/include/SDL2/SDL.h"

//Screen dimensions
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

//Starts up SDL and creates Window
bool init();

//Loads Media
bool loadMedia();

//Close SDL window
void close();

//window to render to
SDL_Window* window = NULL;

SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;

SDL_Surface *player = NULL;

SDL_Rect *playerPos;

bool init()
{
  std::cout << "Initializing" << std::endl;

  //SDL_Init returns -1 if an error occurs, function below to check for error
  if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
  {
    std::cout << "Initialization failed " << static_cast< std::string >( SDL_GetError() );
    return false;
  }

    //Assigning parameters to create window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "CS_version1", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if( window == NULL )
    {
      std::cout << "Window could not be created " << static_cast< std::string >( SDL_GetError() );
    }

    //Get window surface
    screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

    return true;
}


bool loadMedia()
{
  std::cout << "Loading media" << std::endl;

  player = SDL_LoadBMP( "player.bmp" );

  if( player == NULL )
  {
    std::cout << "Media could not be loaded " << static_cast< std::string >( SDL_GetError() );
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

void close()
{
  std::cout << "Closing" << std::endl;

  //Deallocate surface
  SDL_FreeSurface( player );

  //Destroy window
  SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
  window = NULL;

  //Quits SDL
  SDL_Quit();
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{

  if( !init() )
  {
    std::cout << "Initialization failed " << static_cast< std::string >( SDL_GetError() );

    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    //Load Media
    if( !loadMedia() )
    {
      std::cout << "media failed " << static_cast< std::string >( SDL_GetError() );

      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      playerPos->x = 0;
      playerPos->y = 0;
      playerPos->w = 20;
      playerPos->h = 40;

      SDL_BlitSurface(player, NULL, screen, playerPos);

      SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

      SDL_Delay(2000);

    }
  }

  close();

  //Console closes once program ends or error occurs, code used to keep it open
  std::cout << "Enter to continue..." << std::endl;
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Based off what you are saying, means the last executed code is:  player = SDL_LoadBMP( "player.bmp" ); See why SDL_LoadBMP fails with that as an input. Does that bmp file exist locally with the executable?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI I agree that there is a problem with player = SDL_LoadBMP( "player.bmp" ); but I checked after that line, it runs, once it hits the if statement, terminates. And if SDL_LoadBMP did fail the if statement would tell me but it terminates.

Comment: How are you determining that it fails on the null check line and not in the call before it? Also, when it terminates is there a stack trace or any error message?

Comment: @TylerV -- There shouldn't be a stack trace, since the SDL API set the return value to NULL for a specific reason.  It isn't a case where there is an access violation or some other error that would cause the application to terminate due to a crash of some sort.

Comment: @JohnathanRegha-Dodge -- If the `window` is NULL, your application continues as if nothing is wrong.  It shouldn't execute the `SDL_GetWindowSurface` function with a null window.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you call `loadMedia`:

```
   if( !loadMedia() )
    {
      std::cout << "media failed " << static_cast< std::string >( SDL_GetError() );

      return false;
    }
```

You have indicated that when player is null, it fails, but why? If player is null, the function `loadMedia` will return false, putting you in the above if statement.

```
      std::cout << "media failed " << static_cast< std::string >( SDL_GetError() );

      return false;
```

The first line, prints, but you don't see it. This is likely because you don't flush the output stream, and your program ends soon after. Try adding a force flush with `<< std::endl`.

Then the next statement, you return. You are returning from the main function, so your program will exit. Since it is `int main` and you are doing `return false` the value returned is converted from `false` to an `int` which happens to be the value `0`. Returning `0` from main indicates that the program has completed successfully. You could return an error code like `-1` or even throw an exception to indicate to the user that it has failed.

Comment: When main ends, the buffer for `cout` would be flushed, so the line would be visible.

Comment: @Fantastic Mr Fox Thank you for correcting a mistake and in doing so you have made me realize that I did something even more stupid. The player is not null, and the main function continues past if( !loadMedia() ) which I thought it didn't. The real problem are the class variables right underneath, in the main function. For some reason It is stopping the code. Do you know why? Because this is no longer the question I asked should I delete the question after this is solved, or should I just edit it?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Never mind. Ended up solving that problem. What do I do with this question? Since I didn't ask properly and solved the ultimate answer.